# NoSuchMethodError Bundle.getString()

Tags: android

I get some wierd logs, which obviously only occurs on Android-Devices with Versions below 3(checked with emulator).
When you change the orientation and onCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState() is called with an Bundle that is not null it crashed

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);}
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSlug = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_SLUG, null);
    }
}@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_SLUG, mSlug);
}@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
    if (outState != null) {
        mSlug = outState.getString(KEY_SLUG, mSlug);
    }
}
```

The LogCat-Log looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbivQ.png
Does anybody got clue what is happening here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bundle.getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) with 2 arguments is only available in API level 12 and later.  You have to specify the default value yourself, rather than passing it as an argument.

You can check this yourself in the future by clicking the "Filter by API level" dropdown and selecting the appropriate API level in the upper right hand of [the documentation](http://developer.android.com)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Make sure to mark an answer as correct if it answered your question, and upvote it if you would like, as well!

Comment: I had to wait for 10 Minutes to check it as helpful and do not have enough reputation to honor this fast and helpful answer. :/

Comment: No worries, mate!  Some newbies don't read the FAQs and don't know that you are supposed to do these things. :)

Answer (score 3):

Is simple to make

```
mSlug = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_SLUG, null);
```

compatible with olders APIs, just replace it with

```
mSlug = getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_SLUG) ? savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_SLUG) : null;
```

Comment: This isn't the best example since the default 'key not found' return value of getString(key) is already null.  But I see your point and if a non-null default was required this would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function:

```
public static String getStringFromBundle(Bundle bundle, String key, String defaultValue){
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 12){
    String returns = bundle.getString(key);
    if(returns==null) returns = defaultValue;

    return returns;
} else
    return bundle.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Fixed, see comment below.**

For anybody using MvvmCross, there is a bug as of 4.2.3 which is due to this. Just create your own FragmentCacheConfiguration and implement one of the workarounds in this thread.  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1431